# fetching data from users table using supabase but its not logging the data for the specific user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, supabase, supabase-database

i am fetching data from my users table and payments table tied to the user that is logged in, the data for payments connected to the user is logging and also rendering on the page but im not picking up the user information connected to the user, im trying to pull the data as an object that stores the users id and name to create a personal greeting on the dashboard when they log in. Not sure what im doing wrong here:

```
const [sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useState(false)
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState("")
  const [date, setDate] = useState("")
  const [investmentAmount, setInvestmentAmount] = useState(null)
  const [payments, setPayments] = useState([])
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({})

  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
   const getUser = async () => {
    const user = await supabase.auth.getUser();
    console.log(user)
    if (user) {
      const userId = user.data.user?.id
      setUserId(userId)
    }
   };
   getUser()
  },[])


useEffect(()=> {
  const getUserInfo = async () => {
    try {
    const {data, error} = await supabase
    .from('users')
    .select()
    .eq("id", userId)
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log("userData: ", data)
    setUserInfo(data)
  } catch (error){
    console.log("error:",error)
  };
  if (userId) {
    getUserInfo()
  }  
  } 
},[userId])

useEffect(()=> {
  const getPaymentData = async () => {
    try {
      const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from('payments')
      .select()
      .eq("user_id", userId)
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log("data: ", data)
      setPayments(data)
    } catch (error){
      console.log("error: ",error)
    }
  };
    if (userId){
      getPaymentData();
    }
},[userId])
```

Comment: could it be that in the line `.eq()("id", userId)`, it should be `.eq("id", userId)`?

Comment: i spotted that too and fixed it but still getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out, looks like my useffect for getting the user had an error in it, literally copied my useeffect for payments and switched out inputs to grab the users table, then i added the 'select()' method to grab the individual user profile rather than an object with the user info in it which was also posing an issue.

```
 useEffect(()=> {
    const getUserInfo = async () => {
      try {
        const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('users')
        .select()
        .eq("id", userId)
        .single()
        if (error) throw error;
        setUserInfo(data)
        setFirstName(data.first)
        setInterest(data.interest)
      } catch (error){
        console.log("error: ",error)
      }
    };
      if (userId){
        getUserInfo();
      }
  },[userId])
```